# Putting a variable inside an attribute for an HREF tag 

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm new to scripting, trying to change css according to a url variable, using jqURL plugin. For some reason, this does not work for me:

```
 $(function(){

var n= $.jqURL.qs();
alert(n)

$("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : 'n + ".css"'});

});
```

The alert is there for debug, and works well, so it is a matter of how I put the var in the attribute.

This, for example, works fine:

```
if(n == 'red') {
$("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : "red.css"});}
```

Help, please.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("link[rel=stylesheet]").attr({href : n + ".css"});
```